# How to include the session name within SQL command, but make the session name variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a little issue here which i would like to get some help with.

So I'm making a little information site our family, and here we got login and password kind of authentication. I could work that out, but i made a page, which would change info according to the info from the database.

So here is the line which im having the issue with (and other lines work just fine tested and everything):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username,date,info,final,bal FROM tr WHERE id = ? AND username='); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username,$date,$info,$final,$bal);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

and in html:

```
<body class="loggedin">
      <br><?=$username?>
      <br><?=$date?>
      <br><?=$info?>
      <br><?=$final?>
      <br><?=$bal?>
```

Now as you can see all those are variables. These are private info for each user, so I made a database, and put username same as the session name. Now what I want to do is,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username,date,info,final,bal FROM trans WHERE id = ? AND username=');
```

I want to put username = to the name which session gives out to each respective user. I tried putting:
`{$_SESSION['name']}`

`.$_SESSION['name'].v`

`'".$_SESSION['name']."'` to the command line but none of those work. I get an error. So what should I put that it reads the variable and gives the number to MySQL, instead of MySQL going for search on "session_name", I want it to go to lets say "user1" ,which exits in the database. Would appreciate deeply if anyone could help me out on this one.
p.s Not first world problem ,but how to add line breaks between inputs in MySQL? Like instead of showing info1info2,  it shows info1
info2 . Is there a way? thanks for reading!

Comment: Just bind it as another parameter. You won't need to worry about quoting and concatenating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the param you need ($_SESSION['name']) in your query:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username,date,info,final,bal FROM tr WHERE id = ? AND username = ?'); 
// Incorrect.
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']); // Bind id as an int
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['name']); // Bind name as a string
$stmt->execute();
```

Correctly binding multiple params is done like this:

```
// "is" is for two params, int, and string.
$stmt->bind_param("is", $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['name']);
```

Comment: I don't think you can call bind_param multiple times like that. All parameters need to be bound in the same statement. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: it didnt work though. It does not change the info, 2 other users but same info.

Comment: @UnivErsal have you tried storing the session into a variable?
```$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $name);```